# Word VBA if a dialog window is closed, exit macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

it's probably an easy solution for my problem and I hope sb can help me.

I'm opening a Dialog Box in the beginning of my macro with   `Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen).Show` and now I would like to add an If clause that if that Dialog box is closed, the macro stops/exits. I'm not so familiar with the VBA syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog boxes return the following:

The Close button. --> -2

The OK button. --> -1

The Cancel button. --> 0 (zero)

A command button: 1 is the first button, 2 is the second button, and so on. --> > 0 (zero)

**SO:**

```
Sub DialogBoxButtons()
    If Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen).Show = -1 Then
        ' Break or do something else here
    End If
End Sub
```